# Regex to get url or filename in string separated by comma or semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex, url, filenames

I am trying to write a regex pattern which get full path url or just filename with extension.

Input string looks like

> DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45_SM_3.jpg,DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45,4_SM_4.jpg

or

> https://yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_3880_3.jpg;http://www.yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3880_3.jpg

A string can be separated by comma or semicolon

Important! : filename also include a comma!

On the output would like to see accordingly

> DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45_SM_3.jpg
>
> DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45,4_SM_4.jpg
>
> https://yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_3880_3.jpg
>
> http://www.yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3880_3.jpg

Pattern do not cover url, only filenames without path (strings 1 and 2)

```
(?:(?:(?:\w*$).\/)|\w+.{1})\w+.\w+\.\w{3,4}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the separator is either a comma or semicolon and the first char of the filename can not be a comma or semicolon, you could use

```
[^\s,;]\S*?\.\w{3,4}(?![^\s,;])
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\s,;]` Match any char except a whitespace char `,` and `;`
- `\S*?` Match 0+ non whitespace chars, non greedy (As least as possible)
- `\.\w{3,4}` Match a `.` and 3-4 word characters
- `(?![^\s,;])` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not any char except a whitespace char, `,` and `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2GIFwo/1)

```js
const regex = /[^\s,;]\S*?\.\w{3,4}(?![^\s,;])/g;
[
  "DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45_SM_3.jpg,DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3618_45,4_SM_4.jpg",
  "https://yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_3880_3.jpg;http://www.yandex.ru/upload/iblock/f33/DERZHATEL_DLYA_POLOTENETS_3880_3.jpg"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)))
```

If the filename can also start with either `,` or `;` you might use a negative lookbehind to assert what is directly to the left is not any char other than a whitespace char `,` and `;`

See the support for [Lookbehind in JS regular expressions](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

```
(?<![^\s,;])\S+?\.\w{3,4}(?![^\s,;])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HpCxsA/1)

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
(?:^|\/|,|;)([^\/]+?\.\w{3,4})(?=,|;|$)
```

and your matches will be in capture group #1

https://regex101.com/r/ok520U/1